# Windows/Linux dual boot PC fails to boot after power cuts out when removing the Linux partition

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, liveusb, peripherals

I have a Windows PC, but I dual booted Manjaro (Linux) on it to speed up development. Now that I'm done, I want to remove Manjaro and return the PC. I deleted Manjaro partition, but we got a power cut before I was able to finish doing the bootloader stuff on Windows. Now I'm stuck in grub rescue because of an error like:

> "No such device asihdada-ofgdufauyfg-aofapfb-vpawhatever".

The computer uses MBR and Legacy BIOS. I found out the problem could be solved using a Linux (Ubuntu, for now) live USB. I set up a Ubuntu live USB, but when I tried to run it, the computer said "unable to find a medium containing a live file system". My friend told me to disable legacy USB support in BIOS and now my keyboard and mouse won't work. What should I do?

Edit 1: FWIW, I have an available PC to make USBs with, armed with Manjaro and Windows 10 if that would help.

Edit 2: My USB drive is too small for Windows bootable media, so I need a Linux solution. I have an Ubuntu live USB still available, but I face the problem above when trying to boot Ubuntu live.

Edit 3: I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgAP6AqJUpY) to reset BIOS settings and now my keyboard and mouse work again.

Edit 4: A Windows 10 bootable recovery USB should do the trick, and it fits in 512mb if necessary.

Edit 5: Using Windows 10 bootable recovery USB I was able to use the command prompt from the troubleshoot menu, but access was denied to `bootrec /fixboot` which was solved using `bootsect /nt60 SYS`. Now when I reboot I get BSOD with error `INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE`. Startup repair was not able to fix the problem.

Edit 6: Now the computer does not show BSOD anymore, but it automatically boots to Windows Recovery thing.

Edit 7: Nevermind, after removing the USB (why was it booting from it tho??) the BSOD is back, but after rebooting my PC, it attempts startup repair and is not able to fix the problem, but I get to troubleshoot the problem myself now.

FINALE: Turning AHCI mode on from BIOS again and rebooting the PC 4 times made the PC start up to Windows, which is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Grub for booting Windows if you don't use dual-boot any more.

- [Create a Windows 10 boot media](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html)
- [Boot to Advanced Startup Options](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-boot-advanced-startup-options-windows-10-a.html#option5)
- [Run Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Once you can boot into Windows, to complete the task of deleting Linux,
you might enlarge back the Windows partition to include the space liberated
when the Linux partition(s) were deleted.

Comment: I'm not planning to use Grub anymore. Thank you for this answer, but my maximum USB drive size is 3,73gb and Windows seems to be too big for that. That's why I'm trying to boot any live Linux distro and follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzOXlIYB6-8

Comment: If you have a functioning Windows 10 computer, you can [Create a Bootable USB Recovery Drive in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4200-create-recovery-drive-windows-10-a.html). This is probably small enough to fit, but may still do Startup Repair.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Windows recovery USB (with no system files included, it fits in under 500mb) I was able to run `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /rebuildbcd`, `bootsect /nt60 SYS` and `bootrec /fixboot`. After that I turned on AHCI support from BIOS storage settings. Now after rebooting the computer several times, it works.